# How can I check if a string exists in a dictionary inside of a list in python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, if-statement

So, I'm creating this simple battle system as a small project and at the end I need to check if the player has that monster in their team already, however I cannot seem to be able to check all of their team list at once.

Here is the details of the code (not the entire code just the basis for this problem):

```
monster1 = {
    "name": "monster1",
    "type": "Fire",
    "hp": 78,
    "atk": 52,
    "def": 43,
    "spAtk": 60,
    "spDef": 50,
    "spd": 65
}

monster2 = {
    "name": "monster2",
    "type": "Water",
    "hp": 82,
    "atk": 60,
    "def": 32,
    "spAtk": 48,
    "spDef": 60,
    "spd": 70
}

myteam = [monster1, monster2]
eMon = monster2

if eMon not in myteam:
   print("You Won! Would you like to capture this monster?")
   opt = input("y/n ")
```

I've tried using eMon['name'] instead, but it still gives the result as if it is not in the team even if it is.

any solution?

EDIT:
The entirety of the original code:

```
from os import openpty
import random
import time

import os


def clear():
  os.system('clear')


fire1 = 1
fire2 = 0
water1 = 1
water2 = 0
grass1 = 1
grass2 = 0

fireMoves = [fire1, fire2]
waterMoves = [water1, water2]
grassMoves = [grass1, grass2]

moves = [fireMoves, waterMoves, grassMoves]
cyndaquil = {
    "name": "Cyndaquil",
    "type": "Fire",
    "hp": 78,
    "atk": 52,
    "def": 43,
    "spAtk": 60,
    "spDef": 50,
    "spd": 65
}
fennekin = {
    "name": "Fennekin",
    "type": "Fire",
    "hp": 80,
    "atk": 45,
    "def": 40,
    "spAtk": 62,
    "spDef": 60,
    "spd": 60
}
fireTypes = [cyndaquil, fennekin]

totodile = {
    "name": "Totodile",
    "type": "Water",
    "hp": 100,
    "atk": 65,
    "def": 64,
    "spAtk": 44,
    "spDef": 48,
    "spd": 43
}
froakie = {
    "name": "Froakie",
    "type": "Water",
    "hp": 82,
    "atk": 56,
    "def": 40,
    "spAtk": 62,
    "spDef": 44,
    "spd": 71
}
waterTypes = [totodile, froakie]

chikorita = {
    "name": "Chikorita",
    "type": "Grass",
    "hp": 90,
    "atk": 49,
    "def": 65,
    "spAtk": 49,
    "spDef": 65,
    "spd": 45
}
chespin = {
    "name": "Chespin",
    "type": "Grass",
    "hp": 112,
    "atk": 61,
    "def": 65,
    "spAtk": 48,
    "spDef": 45,
    "spd": 38
}
grassTypes = [chikorita, chespin]

allPoke = [fireTypes, waterTypes, grassTypes]
myteam = []


##ADDTOTEAM FUNC
def addToTeam(myteam, allPoke, x, y):
  if allPoke[x][y]["name"] not in myteam:
    myteam.append(allPoke[x][y])
    print(f"{allPoke[x][y]['name']} has been added to your team!")
    return
  else:
    print("Cannot add to Team")
    return


##HPAFFECT FUNC
def hpAffect(pPoke, ePoke, affected, sp, pHealth, eHealth):
  print(f"{pHealth} + {eHealth}")
  if affected:
    if sp:
      pHealth -= (ePoke['spAtk'] - pPoke['spDef'] + 5)
      return pHealth, eHealth
    elif not sp:
      pHealth -= (ePoke['atk'] - pPoke['def'] + 5)

    return pHealth, eHealth
  elif not affected:
    if sp:
      eHealth -= (pPoke['spAtk'] - ePoke['spDef'] + 5)
      return pHealth, eHealth
    if not sp:
      eHealth -= (pPoke['atk'] - ePoke['def'] + 5)
      return pHealth, eHealth
    return pHealth, eHealth

  return pHealth, eHealth


##ATTACK FUNC
def attack(pPoke, ePoke, thisMove, pHealth, eHealth):
  eadd = random.randint(3, 7)
  padd = random.randint(2, 6)
  if thisMove == 0:
    print(f"You used a Special {pPoke['type']} move!")
    if pPoke['spAtk'] + padd > ePoke['spDef'] + eadd:
      print("You won!")
      pHealth, eHealth = hpAffect(pPoke, ePoke, False, True, pHealth, eHealth)
      return pHealth, eHealth
    elif pPoke['spAtk'] + padd < ePoke['spDef'] + eadd:
      print("You lost...")
      pHealth, eHealth = hpAffect(pPoke, ePoke, True, True, pHealth, eHealth)
      return pHealth, eHealth
    else:
      print("You drew.")
      return pHealth, eHealth
  if thisMove == 1:
    print(f"You used a Physical {pPoke['type']} move!")
    if pPoke['atk'] + padd > ePoke['def'] + eadd:
      print("You won!")
      pHealth, eHealth = hpAffect(pPoke, ePoke, False, False, pHealth, eHealth)
      return pHealth, eHealth
    elif pPoke['atk'] + padd < ePoke['def'] + eadd:
      print("You lost...")
      pHealth, eHealth = hpAffect(pPoke, ePoke, True, False, pHealth, eHealth)
      return pHealth, eHealth
    else:
      print("You drew.")
      return pHealth, eHealth


##TURN FUNC
def turn(pPoke, ePoke, pHealth, eHealth, moves):
  global allPoke
  print("What do you wish to do?")
  try:
    opt = int(input("1. attack 2. heal "))
  except ValueError:
    print("Please choose a number.")
    turn(pPoke, ePoke, pHealth, eHealth, moves)
  if opt >= 2:
    clear()
    return
  elif opt <= 1:
    clear()
    y = random.randint(0, 1)
    if pPoke['type'] == "Fire":
      thisMove = moves[0][y]
    if pPoke['type'] == "Water":
      thisMove = moves[1][y]
    if pPoke['type'] == "Grass":
      thisMove = moves[2][y]
    pHealth, eHealth = attack(pPoke, ePoke, thisMove, pHealth, eHealth)
    print(f"Your health is {pHealth} the enemies health is {eHealth}")
    if pHealth <= 0:
      print("You lost the battle! try again?")
      opt = input("y/n ")
      if opt == "y":
        run(allPoke, myteam)
      else:
        return
    if eHealth <= 0:
      if len(myteam) > 5:
        print("You won the battle! try again?")
        opt = input("y/n ")
        if opt == "y":
          clear()
          run(allPoke, myteam)
        else:
          return
      else:
        if ePoke not in myteam:
          print("You Won! Would you like to capture this pokemon?")
          opt = input("y/n ")
          if opt == "y":
            if ePoke['type'] == "Fire":
              for i in range(len(allPoke[0])):
                if allPoke[0][i]['name'] == ePoke['name']:
                  y = i
              addToTeam(myteam, allPoke, 0, y)
              print("try again?")
              opt = input("y/n ")
              if opt == "y":
                run(allPoke, myteam)
              else:
                return
            if ePoke['type'] == "Water":
              for i in range(len(allPoke[1])):
                if allPoke[1][i]['name'] == ePoke['name']:
                  y = i
              addToTeam(myteam, allPoke, 1, y)
              print("try again?")
              opt = input("y/n ")
              if opt == "y":
                clear()
                run(allPoke, myteam)
              else:
                return
            if ePoke['type'] == "Grass":
              for i in range(len(allPoke[2])):
                if allPoke[2][i]['name'] == ePoke['name']:
                  y = i
              addToTeam(myteam, allPoke, 2, y)
              print("try again?")
              opt = input("y/n ")
              if opt == "y":
                clear()
                run(allPoke, myteam)
              else:
                return
          print("try again?")
          opt = input("y/n ")
          if opt == "y":
            clear()
            run(allPoke, myteam)
          else:
            return

        else:
          run(allPoke, myteam)
    else:
      turn(pPoke, ePoke, pHealth, eHealth, moves)


##CALLTEAM FUNC
def callTeam(myteam, attribute):
  for i in range(len(myteam)):
    print(f"{i}: {myteam[i][attribute]}")


##RUN FUNC
def run(allPoke, myteam):
  if len(myteam) < 1:
    x = random.randint(0, 2)
    y = random.randint(0, 1)
    addToTeam(myteam, allPoke, x, y)
  callTeam(myteam, "name")
  x = random.randint(0, 2)
  y = random.randint(0, 1)
  ePoke = allPoke[x][y]
  startBattle(ePoke, myteam)


##BATTLE FUNC
def startBattle(poke, myteam):
  global moves
  opt = None
  print("Choose a pokemon to use:")
  callTeam(myteam, "name")
  try:
    opt = int(input(""))
    if myteam[opt] not in myteam:
      print("Please choose a number that exists.")
      startBattle(poke, myteam)
  except ValueError:
    print("Please choose a number.")
    startBattle(poke, myteam)
  pPoke = myteam[opt]
  print(
      f"You are battling a {poke['name']} and you are using a {pPoke['name']}")
  turn(pPoke, poke, pPoke["hp"], poke["hp"], moves)


run(allPoke, myteam)
```

Thanks for the help, the code is now working as intended.

Comment: If requested, I will show the whole original code.

Comment: Your code works for me. I don't see the `input()` because `monster2` is already in `myteam`.

Comment: It's somehow unclear what you're asking. Your code runs. `eMon` is the same object as `monster2` and it is in the list so nothing will be printed.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I didn't copy and paste my code here, as stated above I WILL if needed, however I tried to edit and simplify my code shown to demonstrate the problem as my script at the moment is quite long, sorry if it was confusing, myteam IS defined above the if statement.

Comment: What do you mean by "I cannot seem to be able to check all of their team list at once"? What should this code do? What does "I've tried using eMon['name'] instead" mean? What exactly did you try? Feel free to show another version of the code to illustrate this more fully.

Comment: [This article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) may help with debugging your full project which seems to have some differences from what you posted here that are causing the problem.

Comment: @Matthias, sorry if it is unclear what I am asking I was trying to show that eMon is equal to a set dictionary. In the original script it is random.

Comment: After looking at your code more closely, I think the problem is that some attributes of the monster changed relative to the version you are comparing with the list. When you compare two dictionaries for equality (which is what the `in` operator will do over the whole list), every key and value pair must be exactly the same. I think it will be better just to check for the name of the monster since you may not know, for example, what its hp is at any given moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**:

I would gather the team names as strings then the rest of your code is basically the same. This seems to be the most simple way.

```
monster1 = {
    "name": "monster1",
    "type": "Fire",
    "hp": 78,
    "atk": 52,
    "def": 43,
    "spAtk": 60,
    "spDef": 50,
    "spd": 65
}

monster2 = {
    "name": "monster2",
    "type": "Water",
    "hp": 82,
    "atk": 60,
    "def": 32,
    "spAtk": 48,
    "spDef": 60,
    "spd": 70
}

my_team = [monster1, monster2]
my_team_names = [e_mon['name'] for e_mon in my_team]
e_mon = 'monster2'


if e_mon not in my_team_names:
   print("You Won! Would you like to capture this monster?")
   opt = input("y/n ")
```

Comment: *Revised naming convention

Comment: What is `e_mon`? Did you try running this code?

Comment: Thanks this helps! This was probably the best way of doing this if I was actually being smart.